# Change Cursor type in Pygtk Application

Tags: python, pygtk, mouse-cursor

In my application I want to change cursor type of all buttons, on mouse leave and enter events. for this, I want to write generalized code instead of connecting each button with appropriate signal.

here's an example code for it.

```
import gtk

class Button(gtk.Button):

   __gsignals__ = {
    "leave" : "override",
    "enter" : "override"
    }

   def do_leave(self):
      self.window.set_cursor(None)

   def do_enter(self):
      print "Enter"
      self.window.set_cursor(gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.HAND2))

class EventBox:

  def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window()
    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    label = gtk.Label("Change Cursor")
    vbox.pack_start(label, False, False)
    bt = gtk.Button('Ok')
    bt.connect('clicked', self.on_click, window)
    vbox.pack_start(bt, False, False)
    eventbox = gtk.EventBox()
    window.set_size_request(400,400)
    window.add(eventbox)
    eventbox.add(vbox)
    window.show_all()

  def on_click(self, widget, window, *args):
    print "On click"
    window.destroy()
    NextWin()

  def mouse_enter_event(self, widget, *args):
    print "Enter"
    widget.window.set_cursor(gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.HAND2))

class NextWin:
  def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window()
    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    label = gtk.Label("Change Cursor")
    vbox.pack_start(label, False, False)
    bt = gtk.Button('Ok')
    vbox.pack_start(bt, False, False)
    eventbox = gtk.EventBox()
    window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
    window.set_size_request(400,400)
    window.add(eventbox)
    window.set_name('Next Window')
    window.set_title('Next Window')
    eventbox.add(vbox)
    window.show_all()

gtk.Button = Button
EventBox()
gtk.main()
```

above code is working for gtk buttons but not working for glade file buttons. 
what could be the problem with glade file buttons?

I'm also looking for more appropriate way to change cursor type. 
Does anyone have any suggestion or correction for above code?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been sitting here for a while, so just a thought...perhaps rebuild your GUI (or some mockup) outside of Glade. It really isn't very hard to do, and the documentation is fantastic.

Then, try and hook up your mouse cursor change codes, and see if it works.